# SharePoint MS Flow - How to send Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks) in Send an Email

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, ms-flow

Could you please help me to send 'Multiple lines of text' column with 'Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)' in MS Flow Email as body. it's coming as Markdown text.

Answer (score 0):

The **Enhanced Rich Text column** does not support **markdown text**.

[image]

Therefore, when sending email using Flow, the converted markdown text will not be displayed.

[image]

Comment: Is there any alternative approach to send a email with Markdown text in MS Flow.

Comment: Hi, Pradeep Kolli. Microsft Flow approval email templates supports "Markdown" at this time. You could refer to this article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/approvals-markdown-support

Comment: I just want to send normal email not any approval email. Could you please suggest on that.

Comment: Hi, Pradeep Kolli. By design, the email sent by Microsoft Flow does not support the Markdown text format.